# How to show part of the_content?

Tags: php, posts, theme-development

i wanna show 20 chars of the_content

i tried this but doesn't work for me .

```
<?php $content = '';
$content = the_content();
$count_content = strlen($content);
   if($count_content > 20 ) {
     $description = substr($content, 0,20,'UTF-8');
     echo $description ;
   }
   else {
     echo $content;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Have you verified that `$content` contains what you think it does? How about running `var_dump()` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Wordpress Codex reference page for `the_excerpt()` as it is a built-in way of doing what you're looking to accomplish:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

EDIT: it also has an example for shortening the excerpt beyond the default length.